# VS 2022 : saved my project but all my code of the day is gone ! where to retrieve the history?

Tags: c#, crash, backup

Strange situation, using VS 2022, and saving my work every 15 min.  My pc started to be unstable (memory saturated) and I saved my project and did EXIT properly from VS.  Restarted my pc and after reopening the project, all the code I did today is gone !  Don't understand.  I added a class, saved it, and the class is gone, nothing in the current folder where the project is. Sounds like I get an older version of the code.

Question : is there any backup or hidden folder where I can expect to retrieve my history ?

Thanks !

Comment: The cs file should be on the machine.  Do a search of the c drive for all cs files changes in the last two days.

Comment: tried already but no result, thanks for your help

Comment: Look under C:\Users\LoginName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\BackupFiles

Comment: thanks, i did already and the folder doesn't contain any recent files

Comment: Can you remember any line of code you wrote? It's drastic, but searching the entire hard drive for file names that contain .cs or the class name you were working on, and where the file contains that text, might turn something up.. For future ref it might be worth at least using something like BitTorrent sync or dropbox to continuously save files elsewhere when they see changes.. Getting into using source control (git) would be a great option too

Comment: yes agree, i will.  I'm searching for some functions name...

Comment: but what I really don't understand is how is it possible that VS is presenting ancient code without any crash?  Is there somewhere any folder where VS is keeping history ? I tried appdata/etc but it's empty.